# How to filter dictionary inside a list by its value matching a condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, lambda, filter

I have the code as follows

```
result = [{"origin_location":'original', 'service':'amazon'},
          {'origin_location':'duplicate', 'service':'flipkart'}]
```

What I want is the result as

```
[{'origin_location':'duplicate', 'service':'flipkart'}]
```

ie, get only those list items where service is flipkart.

I've tried my code for this as follows

```
result = filter(lambda x: (line['service'] for line in result) == 'flipkart', result)
print ("Result= ", result)
```

But it displays [] only. How to correct my code to get the correct output?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` works on an *iterable*. In Python 2.7, it will return a list, while in Python 3.x you have an iterable which can wrapped into a `list`.

So, for example, you do not need a `for` loop within your `filter` statement:

```
lst = [{'origin_location':'original', 'service':'amazon'},
       {'origin_location':'duplicate', 'service':'flipkart'}]

result = list(filter(lambda x: x['service'] == 'flipkart', lst))

print("Result= ", result)

# Result=  [{'origin_location': 'duplicate', 'service': 'flipkart'}]
```

The `lambda` function is applied to each element in `lst`; if it returns `False` the element is "filtered" out.

Note the logic can be implemented more efficiently via a list comprehension:

```
result = [i for i in lst if i['service'] == 'flipkart']
```

If you need to replicate the laziness of `filter`, use a generator expression `(...)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension to only keep the items with this condition

```
>>> result = [i for i in result if i.get('service') == 'flipkart']
>>> result
[{'origin_location': 'duplicate', 'service': 'flipkart'}]
```